# Approaches to choosing number of bins in histogram

Tags: statistics, visualization

Choosing the number of bins in a histogram has always been something that gets me thinking a lot. Based on the number of bins chosen, the graph at time looks a lot different and also could lead to different interpretations.

Below is the **square-root rule**, which I use as the thumb-rule for selecting the number of bins in most occasions.

Posting this question here to hear other opinions.

```py
data_pts = len(np.array(data))
bin_cnt = int(np.sqrt(data_pts))

plt.hist(data, bins=bin_cnt)
```

Comment: This might help:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram

Also there's this Sturges rule whose formula is similar to your code.

Comment: Thanks @FatemehAsgarinejad, that answer does cover a number of methods.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is Bayesian Blocks from [Studies in Astronomical Time Series Analysis. VI. Bayesian Block Representations](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013ApJ...764..167S/abstract) by Scargle et al.

> Bayesian Blocks is a dynamic histogramming method which optimizes one
> of several possible fitness functions to determine an optimal binning
> for data, where the bins are not necessarily uniform width.

[Bayesian Blocks for Histograms](https://www.astroml.org/examples/algorithms/plot_bayesian_blocks.html)